# How to run Jetty on ubuntu?

Tags: java, ubuntu, jetty

I installed Jetty and I run it with `./jetty.sh start`, and it is running:

```
a@a:~/java/jetty/bin$ ./jetty.sh start
Starting Jetty: Already Running!
a@a:~/java/jetty/bin$
```

But when I go to `localhost:8080`, I see

> Error 404 - Not Found. No context on this server matched or handled
>   this request. Contexts known to this server are:
>
> Powered by Jetty:// Java Web Server

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: check your jetty webapps location

    /opt/jetty/webapps
it seems to be empty. If it is, add a war

Comment: I was expecting to see jetty website or some indication that jetty is running. How can I tell if it s running or not running by looking at localhost?

Comment: the statement "Powered by Jetty:// Java Web Server" means Jetty is running fine. Also 404 Error means the server is running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetty is probably running fine - the 404 is coming from the server.  You probably don't have a default web page set to respond to a root request (where something like index.html would be).

Take a look at this: [Jetty - Default page for root path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769950/default-page-for-root-path)

*** EDIT 2013-12-22T16:25Z ***

If you make changes to your application you'll have to release your war file & bounce the Jetty process unless you've got the Jetty deployment set up to automatically refresh the application.

Take a look at this: [Auto-Reloading WAR in Jetty standalone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965643/auto-reloading-war-in-jetty-standalone)

Comment: Thanks, I added the .war file to `/webapp` and I see my hello world page appear. When I update my app, do I need to reload the .war file again?

Comment: Updated the reply in response to clarify. Please do take the time to search StackOverflow for questions that are already answered!